# Preserve line break in string inside array

Tags: php, arrays, string, echo

I am trying to output this string returned to me via API

[image]

but when I print it using this

```
<?php echo $m["page_features"]; ?>
```

it is printed like folloing (single line)

Bunkhouse Front Bedroom Kitchen Island Loft Outdoor Kitchen 4 Slide-Outs

But I want it like

- Bunkhouse
- Front Bedroom
- Kitchen Island
- Loft
- Outdoor  Kitchen
- 4 Slide-Outs

How can I achieve the result as desired output,
please help

Comment: Have you try [n2lbr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)?

Comment: It worked thanks @SimoneRossaini

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for regular line breaks

```
<?php echo nl2br($m["page_features"]); ?>
```

for a UL list:

```
<?php 
$features = explode("\n",$m["page_features"]);
if (count($features)>0){
  echo"<ul>";
  foreach($features as $f) echo"<li>$f</li>";
  echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kinglish  for giving the exact solution

Answer (score 0):

Solution is use php explode function and forloop (any loop) to loop for each value ..
It would be really helpful if you provide complete code !
So taking 2 assumtions first the data recived has br tag and second it has too many whitespaces ....
If i assume the tag used was 
 then  try this one

```
    <?php
    
    $str = "Bunk house <br> Front Bedroom   <br> kitchen <br> island  <br> loft  <br>      etc";
    
    $array = array_filter(explode("<br>",$str));
    
    foreach ($array as $value){
       echo  "<li>".$value."</li><br>";
    }
    
    ?>
```

If I assume  that  there are too many whitespaces inside the string then code becomes

```
   <?php
    
    $str = "Bunk house  Front Bedroom    kitchen island   loft        etc";
    
    $array = array_filter(explode("  ",$str));
    
    foreach ($array as $value){
       echo  "<li>".$value."</li><br>";
    }
    
    ?>
```